# Right way to call suspend function in a PageKeyedDataSource

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

I'm having a hard time with an issue. So basically I'm implementing a paginated list with data brought via the network.

I use the following:

1. Retrofit with suspend
2. MVVM with live data
3. PageKeyedDataSource, DataSource.Factory, and PagedListAdapter

Right now to execute the suspend function I pass a coroutine scope (the view model scope) to the constructor of the data source.

Everything works fine, the pagination works BUT there is a little issue, **submitList()** which is the adapter method to update the data is called before the live data is actually updated so it's size is 0, therefore, **DiffUtil.ItemCallback** is not called to animate the list. The list is updated but without animations.

I think it would be easier if I show you 2 piece of code in **PageKeyedDataSource.loadInitial** with a simplified log:

With coroutine:

```kotlin
// the viewModel scope
scope.launch(getJobErrorHandler()) {
    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.Loading)
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Loading data")
    val result = withContext(withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // retrofit suspend fun
        service.getSearchUsers(query, ApiConstants.DEFAULT_SEARCH_LIMIT, newOffset) 
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Finished loading")
    callback.onResult(result.users, result.next)
    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.SUCCESS)
}
```

In the Fragment

```kotlin
viewModel.users.observe(this@SearchFragment, Observer {
    adapter.submitList(it)
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "submit list with count ${it.size}")
})
```

Log:

```
D/MMF_APP: Loading data
D/MMF_APP: submitList() with count 0
D/MMF_APP: Finished loading
```

Without coroutine:

```kotlin
networkState.postValue(NetworkState.Loading)
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Loading data")

// mock method, non suspend
service.mockGetSearchUsers(query, ApiConstants.DEFAULT_SEARCH_LIMIT, newOffset) 

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Finished loading")
callback.onResult(result.users, result.next)
networkState.postValue(NetworkState.SUCCESS)
```

In the Fragment

```kotlin
viewModel.users.observe(this@SearchFragment, Observer {
    adapter.submitList(it)
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "submit list with count ${it.size}")
})
```

Log:

```
D/MMF_APP: Loading data
D/MMF_APP: Finished loading
D/MMF_APP: submitList() with count 5
```

Note that in both cases the pagination works well, the only difference is that when using coroutines, initially a list of size 0 is set to the adapter and as I mentioned, the **DiffUtil.ItemCallback**  is not called.

Comment: Are you from the future? Retrofit's latest version is 2.8.1

Comment: Must have mixed up with the version of something else, edited the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val result = withContext(withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // retrofit suspend fun
    service.getSearchUsers(query, ApiConstants.DEFAULT_SEARCH_LIMIT, newOffset) 
}
```

Try replacing the above code with the old way of doing things on coroutines:\

```
async {
}.await()
```

Just to be sure it actually waits for something.

Anyway it's probably a paging library issue, it's full of bugs ...

also you paginated list updates a viewmodel livedata? is that right?

Comment: I ended up not doing the pagination since my data was quite small, so now the DiffUtil.ItemCallback animations work fine. I'm not sure if your solution would have worked in my case but if I end up needing pagination I will definitely try it. And yes, I was using LiveData.